# I'm trying to add a shadow to div.logo but it's not working

Tags: html, css, frontend

I tried looking on google but couldn't find anything relevant. I think it's because I transformed it to 1.1 scale but then shouldn't the shadow also increase in size with it?

```
 <body>
    <div id="landing">
        <nav id="main-nav">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#"><img src="./img/logo_final-final.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-btns btns-container">
                <div><a href="#">Home</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Store</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Offers</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">FAQs</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Contact Us</a></div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>

CSS- *{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

#landing{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(/html/img/landing\ background.png) no-repeat center center/cover;
}

#main-nav{
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  background: #007FFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 40px #00000029;
  border-radius: 40px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#main-nav *{
  border: 1px black soli
}
#main-nav .container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

#main-nav .container .logo {
  width: 7%;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px #00000029;
}

#main-nav .container .logo img{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

I don't know how much more detail to write so if you will have any questions let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Hello please try do this css if you agree.

```css
#main-nav .container .logo {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
it looks like the shadow to div.logo works fine
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

#landing{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(/html/img/landing\ background.png) no-repeat center center/cover;
}

#main-nav{
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  background: #007FFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 40px #00000029;
  border-radius: 40px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#main-nav *{
  border: 1px black soli
}
#main-nav .container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

#main-nav .container .logo {
  width: 7%;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px #00000029;
}

#main-nav .container .logo img{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="landing">
        <nav id="main-nav">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#"><img src="./img/logo_final-final.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-btns btns-container">
                <div><a href="#">Home</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Store</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Offers</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">FAQs</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Contact Us</a></div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Edit- Now it seems to work fine. I don't know what happened but it wasn't working. Maybe something wrong with VSCode?

Comment: If you run through VSCode, the hex color code is incorrect **#00000029**

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Thanks